# Random matrices with constraints on row and column length

Tags: random-generation, normalization, markov-process, random-matrix

I need to generate random non-square matrices with $R$ rows and $C$ columns, elements randomly distributed with zero mean, and constrained such that the length ($L_2$ norm) of each row is $1$ and the length of each column is $\sqrt{\frac{R}{C}}$. Equivalently, the sum of square values is $1$ for each row and $\frac{R}{C}$ for each column.

So far I have found one way to achieve this: simply initialize the matrix elements randomly (e.g. from a uniform, normal, or laplace distribution with zero mean and arbitrary variance), then alternately normalize rows and columns to length $1$, ending with row normalization. This seems to converge to the desired result fairly quickly (e.g. for $R=40$ and $C=80$, variance of column length is typically ~ $~0.00001$ after $2$ iterations), but I'm not sure if I can depend on this fast convergence rate in general (for various matrix dimensions and initial element distributions).

My question is this: is there a way to achieve the desired result (row lengths $1$, column lengths $\sqrt{\frac{R}{C}}$) directly without iterating between row/column normalization? E.g. something like the algorithm for normalizing a random vector (initialize elements randomly, measure sum of square values, then scale each element by a common scalar). If not, is there a simple characterization for the convergence rate (e.g. num iterations until error $< \epsilon$) of the iterative method described above?

Comment: This is quite similar to the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm, also alternatively known as iterative proportional fitting.

Comment: Also, you should define what you mean by "random" matrices. For example, the procedure you describe will (almost undoubtedly) not produce random matrices uniformly over the desired space.

Comment: @cardinal Good point.  But note that you can at least achieve identical (marginal) distributions for all the components by post-multiplying by a pair of random permutation matrices (to randomly arrange both rows and columns).

Comment: @whuber: Yes, though the joint distribution could still be quite strange. By "post multiplying" I assume you mean multiplying on the left and right "post-convergence" (rather than, e.g., multiplying on the right).

Comment: Actually, after a little thought, I think you algorithm is ***exactly*** the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm with a very minor modification. Let $X$ be your original matrix and let $Y$ be a matrix of the same size such that $Y_{ij} = X_{ij}^2$. Then, your algorithm is equivalent to applying Sinkhorn-Knopp to $Y$, where at the final step you recover your desired form by taking $\hat{X}_{ij} = \mathrm{sgn}(X_{ij}) \sqrt{Y_{ij}}$. Sinkhorn-Knopp is guaranteed to converge except in quite pathological circumstances. Reading up on it should be very helpful.

Comment: The answer has been given a long time ago by cardinal.

Comment: Thank you for your vote of confidence. I had forgotten about this question. Either I can convert my comment to an answer or you are welcome to reproduce it in an edit to your answer for "safekeeping".

Comment: I would recommend you to just put the answer below

Comment: Yes, cardinal, please convert your comment to an answer. (I had forgotten about this question too.)

Comment: @cardinal, I hope you don't mind, but I'm going to copy your comment into an answer below, just to finish this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @cardinal said in a comment:

> Actually, after a little thought, I think you algorithm is ***exactly*** the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm with a very minor modification. Let $X$ be your original matrix and let $Y$ be a matrix of the same size such that $Y_{ij}=X^2_{ij}$. Then, your algorithm is equivalent to applying Sinkhorn-Knopp to $Y$, where at the final step you recover your desired form by taking $\hat{X}_{ij}=sgn(X_{ij})\sqrt{Y_{ij}}$. Sinkhorn-Knopp is guaranteed to converge except in quite pathological circumstances. Reading up on it should be very helpful.

...it seems that the iterative algorithm I suggested in the original question is very similar to the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm. Interestingly, it also seems very similar to [iterative proportional fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting) (IPF), which, as described on the IPF wikipedia page, is related to Newton's method and expectation maximization (all have the same limit).

These iterative methods are often applied to problems which lack a closed form solution, so I will tentatively assume that the answer to the question is negative: there is no way to achieve the desired solution without row/column iteration.

Comment: (+1)For your continued interest in this question and your independent follow up. :-)